# Android button onClick not working

Tags: java, android, xml, button, onclick

I have avery simple program which uses MediaPLayer. I am new to java and xml and for the life of me can't figue out why the resume button I created won't respond to a click event. It does sit on top of a larger imageButton, which should not repsond in this state, but I think the top level button should regardless, no?

```
package com.whynoceros.tonguechi;

 import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class ArtistsActivity extends Activity {

Button restart, resume, stop;
ImageButton play;
MediaPlayer audio;
boolean playing;
boolean paused;
boolean starting;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tonguechi);
    audio = MediaPlayer.create(ArtistsActivity.this, R.raw.tongue_chi_mix1);

    playing = false;
    paused = false;
    starting = true;
    play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
    stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopbutton);
    resume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resumebutton);
    restart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restartbutton);



}
/*      play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            audio.start();
            play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausebutton2x);
        }

    });
   */ 

public void playNow(View view) {
    if(paused){

    }

    if(playing){
        audio.pause();
        //play.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton2x);
        Animation slideA = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.stopani);
        stop.startAnimation(slideA);
        Animation slideB = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.resumeani);
        resume.startAnimation(slideB);
        Animation slideC = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.restartani);
        restart.startAnimation(slideC);
        playing=false;
        paused=true;
    }
    if(starting){
    audio.start();
    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.pausebutton2x);
    playing=true;
    starting=false;
    paused=false;
    Log.i("play","");


}
}

public void resumeNow(View v) {
    audio.start();
    Animation slideD = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.stopani);
    stop.startAnimation(slideD);
    Animation slideE = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.resumeani_rev);
    resume.startAnimation(slideE);
    Animation slideF = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.restartani_rev);
    restart.startAnimation(slideF);
    play.setEnabled(true);
    playing=true;
    paused=false;
    Log.i("resume","");

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        audio.release();
    }

}





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/playback2x"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/playbutton"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="131dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/playbutton2x"
    android:contentDescription="button"
    android:onClick="playNow"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/resumebutton"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="resume" android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
    android:onClick="resumeNow"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/restartbutton"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="restart" android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopbutton"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="stop" android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"/>



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/playbutton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/tips2x" />


<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="240dp"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="240dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="@string/tips_text"
        android:textColor="#6F372D"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="serif" />
```

Comment: Logcat output pls.......

Comment: Yeah, you gotta do a little more debugging so we can help you.  Try putting a 
Toast.makeText(this, "RESUME CLICKED", Toast.LENTH_SHORT).show();
line at the begging of the resumeNow method.

My guess, however, is that some other view is eating your taps.  Can you post your full XML layout (and the logcat as requested)?

Comment: I have no problems with your code. (of course, i comment out some of your codes). See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my own problem using the following approach:

I replaced all the xml animation with java TranslateAnimation.

I created two separate xml layouts, one for the position of the buttons prior to animation, the other for after. In both layouts, I reference the same buttons, ids, etc...

I created a setAnimationListener each time I begin an animation and then in the onAnimationEnd method, I apply the other xml layout. "setContentView(R.layout.layout2);" Also, immediately after setting the contentView, I had to re-instantiate the buttons, in order to get the click to work.

Now, once the button stops moving, it's actual location is updated to the final location of it's appearance, vis-a-vis the animation.

Answer (score 1):

android:onClick is for API level 4 onwards, so if you're targeting < 1.6, then you can't use it... instead you should use onclicklistener.. i think you are  targeting android 1.5